# MQTT Databaricks,Azure

Tags: azure, databricks, mqtt, publish-subscribe

I am having issues being able to subscribe to payloads from a instance of databricks running.  I have configured a vpn within my dev environment and have my cluster from databricks and virtual machine in it.  My virtual machine is hosting my mosquitto broker.  I can publish anything, but I can only subscribe to "$SYS/#" and no other topics.

Please if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!!

What I have done:

Azure:
Resource Group:
VPN:
-subnets = 10.179.0.0/18

Virtual Machine:

- os = windows 11
- port = 1883
- ip = 10.179.0.6

Databricks Cluster:
I am using mqtt paho to subscribe, but the only tags I can subscribe to is "$SYS/#".  This works just fine.

script:

publish script:

This works:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# Define callback function to handle published messages
def on_publish(client):
  print("Message published successfully.")

# Create MQTT client instance
client = mqtt.Client()

# Set callback function for when message is published
client.on_publish = on_publish(client)

# Connect to broker
client.connect("10.179.0.6", 1883)

# Publish message with QoS of 1
client.publish("paho/test/single", "Test", qos=1)

# Disconnect from broker
client.disconnect()
```

Output:

[image: Here is the output to the broker]

Subscribe script:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt`

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
  print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
  client.subscribe("paho/test/single")


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
  print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("10.179.0.6", 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()

# Blocking call that processes network traffic, dispatches callbacks and
# handles reconnecting.
# Other loop*() functions are available that give a threaded interface and a
# manual interface.
```

`

Output:

[image: Script that reads the broker]

I have tried putting QoS value to 1 instead of 0, but that didn't work.

I have changed the port value in the conf. file on Mosquitto broker

Comment: Please do not post images of code, post the code and format it. Images are hard to read, impossible for those that use screen readers and unsearchable. Also the output image shows both topics starting with `$SYS` and `JeTest`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder on etiquette.  I figured it out.  It was a wild Card.  Thanks